# Excel VBA: Filter Results using Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, filter, textbox

I am using Excel 2010 and I want to get data input from a user typing into a TextBox or ComboBox. I am assuming that you can only use the ActiveX Controls for this.

When I get the data, I want to match it against my results such that it only displays data matching the input of the Text/Combo Box.

Is there an example or a quick way to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into Pivot Tables [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table].
Also [http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-create-pivot-table-chart/]